# Expand multivalued column to new columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I run

Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] Pandas Version: 0.18.1 IPython Version: 4.2.0

on Windows 7 64.

What would be a quick way of getting a dataframe like

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,'a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'d',4],
              [2,'e',5,'f',6,'g',7],
              [3,'h',8,'i',9],
              [4,'j',10]],columns=['ID','var1','var2','newVar1_1','newVar1_2','newVar2_1','newVar2_2','newVar3_1','newVar3_2'])
```

from

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,'a',1],
              [1,'b',2],
              [1,'c',3],
              [1,'d',4],
              [2,'e',5],
              [2,'f',6],
              [2,'g',7],
              [3,'h',8],
              [3,'i',9],
              [4,'j',10]],columns=['ID','var1','var2'])
```

What I would do is to group by ID and then iterate on the groupby object to make a new row from each item and append it on an initially emtpty dataframe, but this is slow since in the real case the rows of the starting dataframe are several thousands.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()]).unstack().sort_index(1, 1)

   var1  var2  var1 var2  var1 var2  var1 var2
      0     0     1    1     2    2     3    3
ID                                            
1     a   1.0     b  2.0     c  3.0     d  4.0
2     e   5.0     f  6.0     g  7.0  None  NaN
3     h   8.0     i  9.0  None  NaN  None  NaN
4     j  10.0  None  NaN  None  NaN  None  NaN
```

---

Or more complete

```
d1 = df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()]).unstack().sort_index(1, 1)
d1.columns = d1.columns.to_series().map('new{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
d1.reset_index()

   ID newvar1_0  newvar2_0 newvar1_1  newvar2_1 newvar1_2  newvar2_2 newvar1_3  newvar2_3
0   1         a        1.0         b        2.0         c        3.0         d        4.0
1   2         e        5.0         f        6.0         g        7.0      None        NaN
2   3         h        8.0         i        9.0      None        NaN      None        NaN
3   4         j       10.0      None        NaN      None        NaN      None        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. This is nice!